# Testing for two conditions in one IF statement

Tags: c#

I realize this like the Hello World level issue but I have to ask. Can these two condition be simplified into one `if` statament?

```
bool isChecked = false;

if(Request["foo"] != null) // Check box
      isChecked = (Request["foo"].ToLower() == "on");

if (!isChecked)
      // do stuff
```

Individually, I get true in both instances, but when I add them onto one `if` statement joined with `&&` I don't get the same outcome.

```
if(Request["foo"] != null && (Request["foo"].ToLower() == "on"))
          // do stuff
```

Comment: What outcome do you get?

Comment: Your `if` statement is in the opposite sense to the original - you're only executing "do stuff" if `isChecked` is *false* in the original code...

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault, If combine the conditions, it always skipps the `do stuff`.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I've tried to change the "on" to "off" bu that didn't help.

Comment: You are checking for false when you say !isChecked. Your "do stuff" comment is reached in 2 different ways.

Comment: Shouldn't the 2nd comparison be != "on"?

Answer (score 2):

It is easier to follow the logic if you simplify it in steps...

first you can shorten your assignment of `isChecked` as follows:

```
bool isChecked = Request["foo"] != null && Request["foo"].ToLower() == "on";

if (!isChecked)
      // do stuff
```

Then we just need to get rid of the `isChecked` variable, which can be done with a simple swap:

```
if (!(Request["foo"] != null && Request["foo"].ToLower() == "on"))
      // do stuff
```

That makes it a bit harder to read and understand, so let's simplify it a bit further. Assuming we have the rule of "do something if Request["foo"] is not set to on" (which is basically what your original logic is doing) then we can do this:

```
if (Request["foo"] == null || Request["foo"].ToLower() != "on"))
      // do stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

You do !isChecked, which is different as what you test. Try this:

```
 if(Request["foo"] != null && !(Request["foo"].ToLower() == "on"))
```

Comment: I must have done something differently as it didn't work this way, even though this make most sense. I've ended up using two separate statements, as I shown it at the top since I need to push this into testing. Thanks to all who contributed.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking is `!isChecked` so your code should be this

```
        if (!((Request["foo"] != null) && (Request["foo"].ToLower() == "on")))
        {
            // Do Stuff
        }
```

The not can be distributed and simplified by inverting all of the checks and the `&&`

```
        if ((Request["foo"] == null) || (Request["foo"].ToLower() != "on"))
        {
            // Do Stuff
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the two tests into:

```
bool isChecked = Request["foo"] != null && Request["foo"].ToLower() == "on";
```

You can also have them in the predicate of an `if` statement.  The reason you can do this is that in C# the `&&` and `||` operators "short-circuit".  That means that if the value of the whole expression can be determined from the left side, the right side is not evaluated.  This is important because in the case where `Request["foo"]` is `null`, you would get an null reference exception if the right side were evaluated.  Testing for null on the left side of an `&&` or `||` is a very common idiom in all of the C-derived languages.